# Running SyntaxNet with designated instance (in Python-level)

Tags: python, nlp, tensorflow, gpu, syntaxnet

Could you please let me know how I designate which instance to use when training/testing SyntaxNet?

In other tensorflow models we can easily change configurations by editing Python code:

ex) `tf.device('/cpu:0')` => `tf.device('/gpu:0')`.

I could run parsey mcparseface model via running `demo.sh` and I followed back symbolic links to find device configurations.

Maybe I misedBut I cannot find gpu configuration python codes in `demo.sh`, `parser_eval.py` and `context.proto`.

When I search with query '`device`' in [tensorflow/models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/), I could see several C files such as [syntaxnet/syntaxnet/unpack_sparse_features.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/a9133ae914b44602c5f26afbbd7dd794ff9c6637/syntaxnet/syntaxnet/unpack_sparse_features.cc) contain line `using tensorflow::DEVICE_CPU;`

So.. is to change C codes in these files the only way to change device configuration for SyntaxNet?

I hope there is a simpler way to change the setting in Python level.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this page for instructions on running syntax net on GPU: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/248

Tensorflow would automatically assign devices including GPU to the ops: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/how_tos/using_gpu/index.html. You can also manually specify the device when building the graph.